# Difference between FileInputStream and ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: java, fileinputstream, bytearrayinputstream

I try to read file type using two ways. It is working while using `ByteArrayInputStream` but not `FileInputStream`

Using `FileInputStream` with `URLConnection`,

```
String fileType = URLConnection
  .guessContentTypeFromStream(
    new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\image.jpeg"))
   ); //fileType = null
```

Using `ByteArrayInputStream` with `URLConnection`

```
String fileType = URLConnection
.guessContentTypeFromStream(
  new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(new File("C:\\image.jpeg").toPath()))
 ); //fileType = image/jpeg
```

Why is the difference in the result ? 
Also, is there anywhere mentioned to use only `ByteArrayInputStream` to read the file type?

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Comment: I am using java 1.8.0_181

Comment: Your first code snippet is not compiling on Java 8... `The constructor FileInputStream(Path) is undefined`

Comment: check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656004/whats-the-difference-between-inputstream-and-bytearrayinputstream), so can get exact idea

Comment: @ernest_k: I have corrected the snippet now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique of `URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream` is to look at the first bytes, the so called *magic cookie* to identify the file.

The implementors chose to leave the Stream in an unaltered state, so continue reading will start (again) with at the beginning.

For that it does a `reset():` to the previous marked stream position (actual the beginning).

```
static public String guessContentTypeFromStream(InputStream is)
                    throws IOException {
    // If we can't read ahead safely, just give up on guessing
    if (!is.markSupported())
        return null;

    is.mark(16);
    int c1 = is.read();
    int c2 = is.read();
    int c3 = is.read();
    ...
    int c14 = is.read();
    int c15 = is.read();
    int c16 = is.read();
    is.reset();
    ....
```

For a sequential FileInputStream `markSupported()` returns the default `false`.

One can solve it by wrapping the `FileInputStream` by a `BufferedInputStream`, which would be faster anyhow.

```
String fileType = URLConnection
    .guessContentTypeFromStream(
        new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("C:\\image.jpeg")))
     );
```

Note that `Files.newInputStream` as stated in the javadoc will not support marking a position for reset.

*(Using a `ByteArrayInputStream` would be a too large overhead.)*

Answer (score 1):

While the two input stream types are different in many ways, the reason for this behavior is only related to those two streams' mark/reset support.

If you check the source of `URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream`, you'll notice:

```
// If we can't read ahead safely, just give up on guessing
if (!is.markSupported())
    return null;
```

And `ByteArrayInputStream` overrides `markSupported` to return `true` whereas `FileInputStream` inherits the default `InputStream.markSupported` method which returns `false`.

In other words, `guessContentTypeFromStream` can't work with a file input stream (or any stream that doesn't support mark/reset).